# How change size of imageView(SubView) in Cell in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with image in cell. More precisely image in assets are bigger than cell. How i can transform image to smaller size?

`   var photos = ["IMG_3814","IMG_3803"]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return photos.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath)
    let img = photos[indexPath.row]
    let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: img))


    cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView)

    return cell
}`
```

Comment: Means you want that the original size will be fit in screen....correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: img))
imageView.frame = cell.contentView.frame
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

it will adjust your image to imageView

Comment: i forgot that you didn't set frame so how it would know how much space to take :)

Comment: wow, it's working. Thanks :) Can you tell me how it's working i mean what is and why is important (that frame)?

Comment: view needs to know how to position itself and how much space it can take

Comment: Thank a lot :) do you know how i can chane space between cells?

Comment: you can set different frame to leave some space on top and bottom, or add headers for every cell. Try to design with Interface Builder in xcode

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 let img = UIImage(named: photos[indexPath.row])
 let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: cell.frame)
 imageView.image = img
 imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
 imageView.clipsToBounds = true
 cell.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: i think need to set frame first